# Update JFrame size and extended State

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen, taskbar

Hello i want to set the size of JFrame, when the user changes the screen resolution.

```
this.setSize(myWidth, myHeight);
```

This is working fine and the window gets smaller/bigger. But if I set the Extended State, it will not affect. I can still see the Menu Bar.

```
this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

Must I call a function, when I'm changing the ExtendedSate and the JFrame is running? In the initialisation, ExtendedState is working fine without calling a function, which rebuild or reload the JFrame.

Comment: Try the [*Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html).

Comment: ExtendedState=Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH makes the OS choose the bounds of the Frame instead of relying on the bounds you may have set in Java. So it all depends what you want to do. Do you want to have full-control and do everything manually in Java (then don't use setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH)), or you want the OS to do the work for you and choose what he considers to be an extended window (then use setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH))

Comment: @GuillaumePolet do you have a tutorial for manually doing this window handling in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no really simple native way, without a lib.